# arguments parsed differently in pycharm and console

Tags: python, shell, pycharm

I was trying to pass some arguments via PyCharm when I noticed that it's behaving differently that my console. When I pass arguments with no space in between all works fine, but when my arguments contains spaces inside it the behavior diverge.

```
def main():
    """
    Main function
    """
    for i, arg in enumerate(sys.argv):
        print('Arg#{}: {}'.format(i, arg))
```

If I run the same function:

```
python3 argumnents_tester.py 'argument 1' argument2
```

Run in **PyCharm**:

> Arg#0: /home/gorfanidis/PycharmProjects/test1/argparse_test.py
>   Arg#1: 'argument
>   Arg#2: 1'
>   Arg#3: argument2

Run in **Console**:

> Arg#0: argparse_test.py
>   Arg#1: argument 1
>   Arg#2: argument2

So, PyCharm tends to ignore quotes altogether and splits the arguments using the spaces regardless of any quotes. Also, arguments with quotes are treated differently than the same arguments without quotes.

Question is why it this happening and at a practical level how am I suppose to pass an argument that contains spaces using PyCharm for example?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 by the way.

Comment: have you try using different type of quote? double quote for `str.format()` in `print()` & single for command argument quoting in pycharm?

Comment: @cryptonome you are right it seems to work with double quotes. If you are willing to provide it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: the thing is i think @guidot is also correct, unless this is strictly not going to be deployed anywhere else, you should consider how the standard works in variety of command lines in the wild, i.e. sh, bash, zsh

Comment: The thing is I expected the same functionality in PyCharm and console, all other are hypotheses about potential use of the code.

Comment: alright i'll compose an answer with a postscript lining up the concern about shell vs pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Background info) Well, an original comment from @cryptonome seemed to work for me but since the provided answer by the same user is not exactly the same I summarized the solution that worked for me.*

PyCharm for some reason treats different single (`'`) and double quotes (`"`) when parsing arguments. Programming in python this may or may not seem natural. Anyway **double quotes (`"`)** seem to work exactly the same both in console and PyCharm. So, when arguments are passed using double quotes (`"`) the same behavior is expected.

Single quotes should be avoided in PyCharm but seem to work in console (at least in mine: *bash* in Ubunut 16.04) because the argument splitting occurs in spaces and not quote boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

What you are complaining about is a shell issue. The shell applies its convention of single quotes to parse arguments. Actually I find the PyCharm behaviour as understandable and consistent; if no shell is involved, nobody does the job you expect.

If you insist on running that from pycharm, I'd suggest another passing method (e.g. via file) or to apply some unquoting mechanism as `urllib.parse.unquote`.

See also [here](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_78.htm) for a dated but still correct description of command line parameters in general, and specifically:

> The ANSI C standard does not specify what constitutes a command-line argument, because operatring systems vary considerably on this point. However, the most common convention is as follows:
>
> Each command-line argument must be separated by a space or a tab character. Commas, semicolons, and the like are not considered separators.

Comment: The definition of ANSI C standard does not make it correct necessarily. And anyway that does not solve the problem of how to parse arguments containing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: What turns out to be the correct solution to @Eypros question was a passing suspicion that it is a matter of difference between how PyCharm implements its arguments parsing in its command-line run & how actual system console/shell behaves, which was also pointed out by @guidot in his answer. I provide more thoughts in Postscript below*.

To circumvent the behaviour exhibited by PyCharm in how it interprets the `argument 1` part in `python3 argumnents_tester.py 'argument 1' argument2` (as *2 arguments*), use a different type of quote in the code, a double quote `"` for `str.format()`, and a single quote `'` for the argument in the run command.

*PS*:
While this seems like a simple workaround, I do think in case of any possibility the code would be executed in any other system, one should choose to adhere to most common/widely accepted standard behaviour of system shells (*bash, zsh, sh*, any *nix flavors) in interpreting the argument passing instead of PyCharm's implementation. This way the code will be much more portable and users don't have to figure out a different way to pass/feed an argument.
As consequence of that, I offer no guarantee this will work aside from this specific way the code formulated & in configuration similar to @Eypros system.

Comment: I was just saying that double quotes works as expected when provided as argument. PyCharm deals single and double quotes differently. That's all. No different code in the code and in the argument.

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear, this workaround worked was because of the difference in PyCharm & shell, not your code per se. so i put the disclaimer & postscript for other PyCharm users who encountered the same issue, that wasn't directed at you.

Comment: I was particularly speaking about your main part of your response. I just had to use `"` instead of `'` in the arguments. So, I was saying this part of your comment was relevant only, not the 2 types of quotes in code and argument part. If you want to edit, otherwise I cannot accept it.

Comment: uh, you mean in my answer i put single quote instead of double quote (and vice versa) when it should be the other way around? i'm not sure i follow

Comment: In your comment you proposed using different quotes: `"`. These are treated in PyCharm as `"` or `'` in bash while `'` are not. So, arguments with spaces within `"` are not split in PyCharm. All other parts of your main answer are not applicable. That's what I was saying.

Comment: the reason i said in my comment to try using different quote type was because i suspected in PyCharm the single quote `'` you used in your code cancelled the single quote `'` used in command argument for its run shell. which is why a `"argument 1"` was treated as a whole string, because that translated to this command in PyCharm run: `python3 argumnents_tester.py '"argument 1"' argument2` (`'` enclosing `"<argument 1>"`); instead of `python3 argumnents_tester.py ''argument 1'' argument2` (`'` enclosing `'<argument 1>'`)